# How to Convert a dataframe into nested dictionary in the following format

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

```
   2  3  4  loc_id 
0  b  b  c       1            
1  b  b  c       6            
2  b  a  b       8            
3  b  b  c      10            
4  b  a  b      11
```

*Can somone help me with converting the above dataframe to the following dictionary in Python with column names as first key and a dictionary inside that with keys as columns values of some columns and values as column values of another column*

```
{2:{'b':[1,6,8,10,11]},3:{'b':[1,6,10],'a':[8,11]},4:{'c':[1,6,10],'b':[8,11]}}
```

Comment: Please, don't post images of code or dataframes, share the actual dataframe so we can copy/paste it

Comment: So what is your question? SO is not a code service website...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) and list for `MultiIndex Series` and then create nested dictionary:

```
s = df.melt('loc_id').groupby(['variable','value'])['loc_id'].agg(list)

d = {level: s.xs(level).to_dict() for level in s.index.levels[0]}
print (d)
{'2': {'b': [1, 1, 6, 8, 10, 11]}, 
 '3': {'a': [8, 11], 'b': [1, 1, 6, 10]}, 
 '4': {'b': [8, 11], 'c': [1, 1, 6, 10]}}
```

Or create dictionary of `Series` and aggregate index to list:

```
d = {k: v.groupby(v).agg(lambda x: list(x.index)).to_dict() 
     for k, v in df.set_index('loc_id').to_dict('series').items()}
```